# Unity - drag to resize / scale plane based on handle position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale, mesh

Alright, I cant find any example of this already done and my attempt is yielding odd results - I need to drag to resize a flattened cube (like a plane, but must have thickness so it was a cube) using a handle in the corner. Like a window on your desktop.

So far Ive created my handle plane and gotten it via script attached to my cube plane. The cube plane and the handle are children of an empty to which the scale is being applied so that the cube plane scales from left to right as desired:

[image]

That works, however my attempt at using the delta scale handle position to scale the parent empty scales either way too much or in odd directions:

```
Awake() {
scaleHandle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ScaleHandle");
        scaleHandleInitialPos = scaleHandle.transform.localPosition;
}

Update()
{

width += -1*(scaleHandleInitialPos.x - scaleHandle.transform.localPosition.x);
        height += -1 * (scaleHandleInitialPos.y - scaleHandle.transform.localPosition.y);

        transform.parent.localScale = new Vector3(width, height, thickness);
}
```

what is wrong here?

Hierarchy:

[image]

Transform of the child:

[image]

With updating initialPos every `Update()` OR doing `width =  scaleHandle.transform.localPosition.x / scaleHandleInitialPos.x;` where the white square is the scaleHandle

[image]

Comment: Is any of the objects rotated/scaled differently? Would probably help to see the hierarchy and each transforms settings

Comment: Why do you add the delta scale to the size? If you do that you should change `scaleHandleInitialPos` after every update too.

Comment: @derHugo see my edit

Comment: Have you tried using something like `width =  scaleHandle.transform.localPosition.x / scaleHandleInitialPos.x;` and same for height?

Comment: @shingo when I do that the scaleHandle moves increasingly away from its corner

Comment: @derHugo when I do that the scaleHandle also moves increasingly away from its corner - see the image above

Comment: @skyguy, when the parent's scale is changed, it also affects the child's transform. Do you have any reason to set the handle as a child of the target plane?

Comment: @shingo no, but I tried moving it out of the parent and got same results

Comment: Since there is no code changes the handle's position, how could be same?